# Reading value from cookie in asp.net core

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, knockout.js

I have a problem with reading cookies. In first request I add cookie with method

```
Response.Cookies.Append("UserName", "Name", new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions()
        {
            Path = "/",
            HttpOnly = false,
            Secure = false
        });
```

In next request I want to read value from cookies

```
 var name = Request.Cookies["UserName"]
```

but Request.Cookies is null. But also, when I call this method by typing api in browser

```
localhost:5555/api/tempController/getCurrenUserName
```

`var name = Request.Cookies["UserName"]` returns me a value and `Request.Cookies` contains all cookies, which I see in browser.

I don't understand, why in one case it works in another does not work.

Comment: I forget one thing:
I am using knockout.js.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with method fetch in knockout.js, I replaced it with jQuery methods and now it works!!!